# security considerations when using (end-user-defined) JavaScript code inside Java

Tags: javascript, java, security, javax.script, graaljs

I am working on a Java project. In it, we want to enable an end-user to define variables which are calculated based on a set of given variables of primitive types or strings. At some point, all given variables are set to specific values, and then the calculations should be carried out. All resulting calculated variables must then be sent to Java.

I am in the process of evaluating ways for the end-user to define his calculations. The (current) idea is to let him write JavaScript and let that code be interpreted/executed inside the Java program. I know of two ways for this to be done: Either use the javax.scripting API or GraalVM/Truffle. In both, we would do it like this:

1. The given variables are given into the script. In javax.scripting via `ScriptEngine.put`, in Graal/Truffle via `Value.putMember`.
2. The end-user can define variables in the global context (whose names must not collide with the ones coming from Java). How he sets their values is up to him - he can set them directly (to a constant, to one of the given variables, to the sum of some of them ...) or define objects and functions and set the values by calling those.
3. When the time comes where the given variables have a fixed value, the script is executed.
4. All variables that were defined in the global context by the script will be sent to Java. In javax.scripting via `ScriptEngine.get`, in Graal/Truffle via `Value.getMember`.

*NOTE:* We would not grant the script access to any Java classes or methods. In javax.scripting via check if the script contains the string `Java.type` (and disallow such a script), in Graal/Truffle via using the default `Context` (which has `allowAllAccess=false`).

The internet is full of hints and tips regarding JavaScript security issues and how to avoid them. On the one hand, I have the feeling that none of them apply here (explanation below). On the other hand, I don't know JavaScript well - I have never used it for anything else than pure, side-effect-free calculations.

So I am looking for some guidance here: **What kind of security issues could be present in this scenario?**

---

Why I cannot see any security issues in this scenario:

This is pure JavaScript. It does not even allow creating Blobs (which are part of WebAPI, not JavaScript) which could be used to e.g. create a file on disk. I understand that JavaScript does not contain any functionality to escape its sandbox (like file access, threads, streams...), it is merely able to manipulate the data that is given into its sandbox. See this part of https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-overview:

> **ECMAScript is an object-oriented programming language for performing
> computations and manipulating computational objects within a host
> environment. ECMAScript as defined here is not intended to be
> computationally self-sufficient; indeed, there are no provisions in
> this specification for input of external data or output of computed
> results.** Instead, it is expected that the computational environment of
> an ECMAScript program will provide not only the objects and other
> facilities described in this specification but also certain
> environment-specific objects, whose description and behaviour are
> beyond the scope of this specification except to indicate that they
> may provide certain properties that can be accessed and certain
> functions that can be called from an ECMAScript program.

The sandbox in our scenario only gets some harmless toys (i.e. given variables of primitive types or strings) put into it, and after the child has played with them (the script has run), the resulting buildings (user-defined variables) are taken out of it to preserve them (used inside Java program).

Answer (score 4):

(1) Code running in a virtual machine might be able to escape. Even for well known JS implementations such as V8 this [commonly happens](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=v8). By running untrusted code on your server, whenever such a vulnerability becomes known, you are vulnerable. You should definitely prepare for that, do a risk assessment, e.g. which other data is accessible on the (virtual) machine the engine runs on (other customers data?, secrets?), and additionally harden your infrastructure against that.

(2) Does it halt? What happens if a customer runs `while(true);` ? Does that crash your server? One can defend against that by killing the execution after a certain timeout (don't try to validate the code, this will never work reliably).

(3) Are the resources used limited (memory)? With `a = ""; while(true) a += "memory";` one can easily allocate a lot of memory, with negative impact on other programs. One should make sure that also the memory usage is limited in such a way that the program is killed before resources are exhausted.

Comment: While the second one is a theoretically unsolvable problem, it can easily be avoided by only giving the code a limited amount of time to finish or consider it broken (i.e. start it with a timeout).

Answer (score 2):

Just some thoughts.  You're essentially asking if you can trust your sandbox/vitual machine, for that you should either assume that you're using a good one or the only way to be really sure is to read through all its source code yourself.  If you choose a trusted and well known sandbox, I'd guess you can just trust it (javascript shouldn't be able to affect file system stuff outside of it).

On the other hand why aren't you just doing all this calculations client side and then sending the result to your backend, it seems like a lot of setup just to be able to run javascript server side.  If the argument for this is "not cheating" or something similar, then you can't avoid that even if your code is sent to the server (you have no idea who's sending you that javascript).  In my opinion doing this setup just to run it server side doesn't make sense, just run it client side.

If you do need to use it server side then you need to consider if your java is running with root permissions (in which case it will likely also invoke the sandbox with root permissions).  On my setup my nodejs is executing under ~/home so even if a worst case happens and someone manages to delete everything the worst they can do is wipe out the home directory.  If you're running javascript server side then I'd strongly suggest at the very least never do so under root.  It shouldn't be able to do anything outside that sandbox but at least then even in the worst case it can't wipe out your server.

Something else I'd consider (since I have no idea what your sandbox allows or limits) is whether you can request and make API calls with javascript in that sandbox (or anything similar), because if it's running under root and allows that it would give someone root access to your infrastructure (your infrastructure thinking it's your server making requests when it's actually malicious JS code).

You could also make a mistake or start up your VM with an incorrect argument or missing config option and it suddenly allows a vulnerability without you being aware of it, so you'll have to make sure you're setting it up correctly.

Something else is that if you ever store that JS in some database, instead of just executing it, then you have to make sure that it's not made directly available to any other users without checking it otherwise you'd have XSS happening.  For example you build an app for "coding tests" and store the result of their test in a database, then you want to show that result to a potential employer, if you just directly display that result to them you'll execute malicious code in their browser.

But I don't really see a reason why you should care about any of this, just run it client side.